# Complex numbers equation with modulus and De Moivre's formula

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I have a problem with the following question.

For which $n$ does the following equation have solutions in complex numbers

$$|z-(1+i)^n|=z $$

Progress so far.

1. Let $z=a+bi$.
2. Since modulus represents a distance, the imaginary part of RHS has to be 0. This immediately makes $b=0$.
3. If solutions are in the complex domain $|a-(1+i)^n|=a $ by 2., and $a$ is Real.
4. ?

I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, no such solutions exist since LHS is purely real and the RHS would be purely imaginary in your question. If you want to know for what values of $n$ do we get $z \in \mathbb{Q}$ or even $\mathbb{Z}$, that could lead to some interesting results.

Comment: Actually, the question generally asks for solutions from the complex domain, not exactly the purely imaginary ones. I just edited the description for that.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break the problem into two parts. (I) Find the set $S$ of all complex numbers $z_0$ such that the equation $|z-z_0|=z$ has a solution. (II) Determine the set of all integers $n$ such that $(1+i)^n\in S$.

(I) The equation $|z-z_0|=z$ says that $z$ is a nonnegative real number and is equidistant from $z_0$ and $0$. In the trivial case $z_0=0$, every nonnegative real $z$ satisfies the equation. Otherwise, the condition for the equation to be solvable is that the perpendicular bisector of the straight line segment joining $z_0$ to $0$ intersects the positive real axis. Clearly, this holds if and only if $z_0$ lies to the right of the imaginary axis. Thus $S=\{0\}\cup\{z:\Re(z)\gt0\}$.

(II) Since $(1+i)^n=2^{n/2}(\cos\frac{n\pi}4+i\sin\frac{n\pi}4)$, we have $(1+i)^n\in S$ just when the angle $\frac{n\pi}4$ is in the open right half-plane, that is, when $n=8t$ or $n=8t\pm1$, $t=0,\pm1,\pm2,\pm3,\dots$.

If $n=8t$, then $(1+i)^n=2^{4t}$, and the solution of the equation is $z=\frac12(1+i)^n=2^{4t-1}$, the midpoint of $0$ and $(1+i)^n$.

If $n=8t\pm1$, then $(1+i)^n=2^{4t\pm\frac12}(\cos\frac\pi4\pm i\sin\frac\pi4)$, and the solution of the equation is $z=\Re(1+i)^n=2^{4t\pm\frac12}\cos\frac\pi4=2^{4t-\frac12\pm\frac12}$, i.e., $z=2^{4t}$ if $n=8t+1$ or $z=2^{4t-1}$ if $n=8t-1$, in either case making an isosceles right triangle with $0$ and $(1+i)^n$.

Answer (score 1):

- Obviously, *z* is a point on the positive semi-axis, since absolute values are always positive reals.
- $|z_1-z_2|$ represents the distance between two points on the complex plane.
- Therefore, *z* is equally distanced from the origin *O*, and from $A_n=(1+i)^n$. This implies that it lies on the perpendicular bisector of the segment $(OA_n)$.
- Since *n* is a natural number, and since the angle between $A_1=1+i$ and the positive semiaxis is $45^\circ$, it follows that, with each successive multiplication, the angle between the segment $OA_k$ and the positive semiaxis grows by $45^\circ$, until it resets on the eighth turn, since $360^\circ/45^\circ=8$.
- But on which of these eight cyclically repeating situations does the perpendicular bisector of the segment $(OA_n)$ actually meet or intersect the positive semiaxis ? Obviously, it can only happen for $n\equiv0,\pm1\mod8$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $z$ is equal to the absolute value. Therefore $z$ has to be real. Thus it has no purely imaginary solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $1+i=\sqrt{2}(\cos(\pi/4)+i\sin(\pi/4))$. We have

$|z-(1+i)^n|=|z-(\sqrt{2})^n(\cos(n\pi/4)+i\sin(n\pi/4))|=z$

$\sqrt{(z-(\sqrt{2})^n\cos(n\pi/4))^2+(\sqrt{2})^{2n}\sin^2(n\pi/4)}=z$

so

$(z-2^{n/2}\cos(n\pi/4))^2+2^n\sin^2(n\pi/4)=z^2$,

$-2^{n/2+1}z\cos(n\pi/4)+2^n\cos^2(n\pi/4)+2^n\sin^2(n\pi/4)=0$,

$2^{n/2+1}z\cos(n\pi/4)=2^n$,

$$z=\frac{2^{n/2-1}}{\cos(n\pi/4)}$$

whenever $n$ is odd; for $n$ even there is no solution.

Comment: When $n=0$, $z=\frac12$ is a solution; when $n=\pm8$, $z=8$ is a solution; etc.

Answer (score 0):

$|z-(1+i)^n|=z$. LHS $\in \mathbb{R}$ so clearly $z \in \mathbb{R}$. I'll rewrite $z$ as $a$. $(1+i)^n =(\sqrt2)^ne^{\frac{in\pi}{4}}$.

Thus, RHS is the square root of $(a-(\sqrt2)^n\cos(\frac{n\pi}{4}))^2+((\sqrt2)^n\sin(\frac{n\pi}{4}))^2$ (it is getting cumbersome so I didn't include the square root).

Thus we get $a^2 -2a(\sqrt2)^n\cos(\frac{n\pi}{4})+2^n\cos^2(\frac{n\pi}{4})+2^n\sin^2(\frac{n\pi}{4})=a^2$. After some algebraic manipulation:

$a(\sqrt2)^n\cos(\frac{n\pi}{4})=2^{n-1}$ and thus $a=\frac{2^{n/2-1}}{\cos(\frac{n\pi}{4})}$.

By the way, $\cos(\frac{n\pi}{4})=1,\frac{1}{\sqrt2},0,\frac{-1}{\sqrt2},-1,\frac{-1}{\sqrt2},0,\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ for $n=0,...,7$ before repeating.

So given an $a$, you can find the zeros of $a-\frac{2^{n/2-1}}{\cos(\frac{n\pi}{4})}$. But based on what we know about $\cos(x)$, not all values of $a$ will work and also some values of $n$ will make the denominator equal to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

You already found that z has to be real, now just write out $|z| = \sqrt{Re(z)^2 + Im(z)^2}$
Note that $i+1 = \sqrt{2} e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}} = \sqrt{2} \cos(\frac{\pi}{4}) + i\sqrt{2} \sin(\frac{\pi}{4})$
Then you need to find when $a^2 =|a-(1+i)^n|^2 = a^2 + 2 \cdot 2^\frac{n}{2} a \cos(\frac{\pi}{4}n) + 2^n$
That is, finding the zeroes of $2 \cdot 2^\frac{n}{2} a \cos(\frac{\pi}{4}n) + 2^n$
For small z this has solutions around $n \approx -2-4k$ (because the cos is zero and $2^n$ is negligible) but the only way this can be true for all z is  in the limit $n\rightarrow - \infty$